# Not loading AVD platform 4.0 (API Level 14) in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am using Eclipse SDK version 3.7.1 and in Windows 7. I am able to run older AVD but can't load the Platform 4.0 (API Level 14). What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder you haven't installed **ARM EABI v7a System Image** while update/installing Android 4.0. Make sure all the dependencies are installed correctly.
Cheers

Comment: I was also facing same kind of problem before installing the system image described above..

Answer (score 0):

did you install the plugin for android4.0???
If you didnt install then follow the instruction given in the following link to install the plugin.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

now open the eclipse IDE and click on white colored down arrow image button in the tool bar of the IDE to open the Android SDK Manager.now select packages which are not installed and click on install packages button to install the API 14.It will take some time to install.After the installation you'll find that now API 14 is loaded in eclipse.Now enjoy the android4.0.I hope you find this answer useful.